# Modal with bootstrap, show value from textarea

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap modals and I'm trying to show in the modal the value of a textarea, here the code:

```
<textarea name="text" id="moderador" rows="20"><?=trim($contenido)?></textarea>
```

And the modal:

```
<div id="previa" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Vista Previa</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body" id="modals">
    <script>
        $("#modals").html($("#moderador").val());
    </script>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cerrar</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is.. when i add something in the textarea, the modal didn't show, only show the 1st value, don't update the information, what can i do?

sorry for my english!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be best to set the value of the modal as you are displaying it.  This would mean you need to toggle the modal using JavaScript, and not using a data-attribute.  For example:

```
  $('#showModal').click(function() {
    $("#modals").html($("#moderador").val()); 
    $('#previa').modal();
  });
```

Here's a quick example plunker:  http://plnkr.co/edit/iPcQGE78vM5t7k3PZPHx?p=preview